# Limiting the number of characters shown in a Boundfield for gridview

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I have a gridview that shows a user's name, a subject, and a date. The .aspx code looks like this:

```
      <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" 
            SortExpression="UserName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Subject" 
            SortExpression="Subject" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" 
            SortExpression="Date" />
```

If the user enters a subject that is say 200 characters, I don't want it to all show otherwise the page will be stretched like crazy. Is there any way to do a check so that if the subject is more than say 60 characters, the rest is taken off and a ... is just appended on? So the subject would go from say:

This is a realllllllllllllllllllllllly long subject

to

This is a reallllll....

I know how to do it in the C# code behind but not sure how to manipulate it in the .aspx

Comment: Use `TemplateField` and `Eval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# ((string)Eval("Subject")).Length < 200? Eval("Subject") :((string)Eval("Subject")).Substring(0,200) + "..."%>)
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Alternatively (and more cleanly) you can (if possible) add a property to your datasource item-class and use that property in normal fashion. Say, your data-source item class is `UserMail`; then add a public property say `TruncatedSubject` like:

```
partial class UserMail
{        
    public string TruncatedSubject
    {
       get
       {
           return Subject.Length < 200? Subject : (Subject.SubString(0,200) + " ...");
       }
    }        
}
```

then you can use it (`TruncatedSubject` instead of `Subject`) like a normal `BoundField` column.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do I add a property to my datasource item-class? I honestly have no idea what that even means really

Comment: If the class is auto-generated (by EF or other framework) it is marked as **partial**. And you can always add stuffs to a partial class using just the keyword _partial_ like above. More about partial classes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.80).aspx